# How to set Am/PM in Angular material date range picker forms

Tags: angular, datetime, angular-material

I am using Date range picker forms from angular material. When I pick date range let say 1mar-4mar I get end date 4 mar 12:00pm isn't it should be 4 mar 11:59pm? how to solve this problem.

Here is my demo code: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5hgnk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-forms-example.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular materials does not support time picking at the moment...

If you have look at the [documentation for DatePicker's](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview), you will notice it does not mention time picking.

That's the issue you are facing. Here is the [issue tracker](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5648) for the feature

To resolve your time issue you will need to implement the smarts of time handling separately from the vanilla Materials DatePicker results, or use a third party component with time picking capabilities.